# Deleting Messages a bot has sent Discord.net

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I am attempting to create a bot that has the ability to delete only the bots messages after a command has been done.
I am aware of how i know that the command has taken place however I am having issues with only deleting the messages that the bot has sent.

```
    await Message.ModifyAsync(msg => msg.Content = "test [edited]");
```

However this only occurs to the last message that has been sent (This can be fixed relatively easily and I know how to do this) and importantly would otherwise occur to all the messages in the chat!  What i want to do is make it so that I only delete messages that were sent by the bot in the first place.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get and store the message that the bot sent as a variable, and delete it later.

```
var botMsg = await ReplyAsync("A message!");
await botMsg.DeleteAsync();
```

If you need to delete multiple messages, create a list and store each message to the list. Then use `await Context.Channel.DeleteMessagesAsync(list)` at the end of the command.

#### EDIT

There are overload methods for passing both list of message ID and the message itself.
Example of passing a list of message ID:

```
List<ulong> msgToDel = new List<ulong>();
msgToDel.Add((await ReplyAsync("test1")).Id); //Send a msg, then add the msg ID to the list.
msgToDel.Add((await ReplyAsync("test2")).Id);
//Blah...
await Context.Channel.DeleteMessagesAsync(msgToDel);
```

You can check the documentation for the `DeleteMessagesAsync()` [here](https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.IMessageChannel.html#Discord_IMessageChannel_DeleteMessagesAsync_IEnumerable_System_UInt64__Discord_RequestOptions_).

Comment: Ok, do i store a message id or plain text in the list. Do you have a working demo if possible and I'll accept this

Comment: @15wshepth I edited my question to answer that, check it.